# How can I set an entire select option object as a model?

Tags: angularjs, multi-select

I found that the selected model contains only the id property of an option object property. Is it possible for the selected model to contain the whole object?

HTML

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="exampleData" selected-model="exampleModel"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.exampleModel = []; 
$scope.exampleData = [ 
   {id: 1, code: 'CA': label: "California"}, 
   {id: 2, code: 'MN' label: "Minnesota"}, 
   {id: 3, code: 'NY', label: "New York"} ];
```

So, in this case, if I select the first option, the model becomes the following:

```
$scope.exampleModel = [{"id":"CA"}]
```

I need the model to contain the whole option object as follows:

```
$scope.exampleModel = [{id: 1, code: 'CA': label: "California"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update it on the `onSelectionChanged` callback event.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.exampleModel = [];
  $scope.exampleData = [{
    id: 1,
    code: 'CA',
    label: "California"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    code: 'MN',
    label: "Minnesota"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    code: 'NY',
    label: "New York"
  }];
  $scope.exampleEvents = {
    onSelectionChanged: function() {

      $scope.exampleModel.forEach(function(selectedData) {
        var data = $scope.exampleData.find(function(item) {
          return item.id == selectedData.id;
        });
        if (data != null) {
          angular.copy(data, selectedData);
        }
      });
      console.log("Change:", $scope.exampleModel);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/1.11.8/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="exampleData" selected-model="exampleModel" events="exampleEvents"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

add externalIdProp : '' to extra settings like below:
{enableSearch: true, scrollableHeight: '400px', scrollable: true, externalIdProp : ''}

Here's the link https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/issues/396